# MediaPlayer loops when started from onPause()

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, onpause

I want to play a sound when `onPause()` of my Activity is called. To do so, I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.start();
}
```

This works fine, but the sound keeps on playing forever. I tried adding an `OnCompletionListener`, but that didn't help (the `Listener` is never called).

I know that I'm not calling `player.stop()` and `player.release()` anywhere, but I wouldn't even know where to do so.

My question is now: How can I make the sound play only **once**? Is there a way to wait for the media player to finish before the application goes to the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

The problem was, that I was using `Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI`, which apparently never stops playing.

Using `Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI` instead fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if I've understood correctly)

```
public boolean test=false; // At begin

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
if(!test){
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.start();
    test=true;
}
}
```

Maybe I don't understand what you want to say. If you explain us a little bit more, maybe we can help to you :)

Comment: The problem is not that `onPause` is called repeatedly, the app goes to the background, but the sound keeps playing.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this,, but I think you can check this one

```
       player.setLooping(false);
       player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what wwas the exact problem with onCompletionListener?? I thought it should work

Comment: The problem is that the listener is not called, i.e. the contained code is never executed.

Comment: have you set the listener after start()?

Comment: Tried it before and after `start()`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why it plays in loop but you can you use MediaElement to play sound? You can identify when media is ended by using method MediaEnded and then call stop method to stop playing audio

Comment: Do not have code is C but below code works in VB.net     Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs) bmusicplay = true